# Reusable chunks of html code

Tags: javascript, html, modularity

I have a few html components that have I customized with some javascript. For example, I have a list with a button to add and remove items from the list. I'd like to be able to reuse these components, but I'm not sure the best way to go about it (this particular project is Spring MVC).

Options I've considered are jsp fragments that can be included in other pages or custom tags. Are there alternatives that do not require using the server (e.g. tag processing). If I just have some html/javascript pieces that get used together, it seems like there should be an easy way to make them modular.

Answer (score 0):

Most JS UI frameworks provide their UI components by creating them entirely in JS.  This may be your best bet as it is independent of your server-side frameowork (you could use it with ruby, php, .net) and it keeps your HTML clean.

For your list w/ button example, you would render both the list and the button from a JS function called on a standard HTML object.  In your case, if you are using your MVC framework to write data to the list, you may choose to continue doing that and write your JS creation logic to accept a list as an input, then render your advanced styling and UI (like the button) around it.  This lets you still accept data from the server side as normal and gives your HTML code a similar appearance to the final product (it would just be missing the add/remove buttons), but lets you re-use your HTML/JS logic as much as possible.

If your current code looks like this:

```
<div class="addremovelist">
    <select>
        <option>blah</option>
        <option>blah</option>
        <option>blah</option>
    </select>
    <div class="addremovebuttons">
        <input type="button" value="Add" />
        <input type="button" value="Add All" />
        <input type="button" value="Remove" />
        <input type="button" value="Remove All" />
    </div>
<div>
```

You would now write it like this:

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option>blah</option>
    <option>blah</option>
    <option>blah</option>
</select>
```

With the following javascript in your window load event:

```
$('#myselect').addRemoveList({myoptions: 'ifnecessary'});
```

Or something like that

Comment: If SEO is a concern for you should make sure you're aware of the impact rendering html content with JS has there (mainly it won't be seen by crawlers)

Comment: Thanks @MattBerkowitz, I've updated my example with an SEO friendly implementation.  This may not be screen reader friendly though :(

Comment: @MichaelLaVoie that idea has come up as well, but it seems a little offputting that I would need to use javascript to render what is basically static html code

Comment: @JeffStorey I agree 100%.  It's a shame that you can't bundle html, CSS and JS fragements together in a nice package for deployment.  However, if JQuery UI and the other big libraries haven't found a better way, I suspect this is a limitation of the web.